# Can i use SQL Server Compact Edition 3.5 without Visual Studio

Tags: sql, sql-server-ce

Can i use SQL Server Compact Edition 3.5 without Visual Studio. I install SQL Server Compact Edition but can't find where i create database.

Please guide me i have to install sql server on client computer for runing my project without visual studio.

Comment: you can use sqlCE without Visual studio.  usually the file has an extension of .sdf, but it could be anything.  Try a file search for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here ([link](http://erikej.blogspot.ro/2009/04/sql-compact-3rd-party-tools.html)), you have a huge list of tools (commercial and free) for SQL CE.